# How to disable Location Services using Siri?

Tags: iphone, ios, siri

Which sentence should I say to disable Location Services using Siri? Saying "disable location services" she says she is unable to do that!

Comment: You can say "Open Location Services" though, which will take you right to the slider in the appropriate settings screen to manually turn it off. Closest thing to a solution that can be done right now given Siri's limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Siri is currently unable to enable/disable Location Services. You'll have to use Settings.

Answer (score 0):

say 'hide my location' and 'don't hide from my friends'